# problemas em pega um ID especifico e checar se na outra tabela existe

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, mysqli, phpmyadmin

estou criando um sistema de controle, onde tenho 3 níveis de usuario, sendo: admin, aluno e diretor.

no sistema o usuario adiciona links e consegue acompanha o progresso da mesma, como: views,curtidas,comentarios e etc.. estou criando a view do admin para ta listando os dados do usuario como escrito acima, mais pode acontecer do usuario ter mais de um link e sera necessario mostra todos eles, minha dificuldade é trazer todos esses links, no momento so estou conseguindo trazer apenas uma.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Bom dia, pelo o que entendi, a questão pode estar no `where`, ao invés de:

```sql
pessoas_has_links.id
```

deveria ser

```sql
pessoas_has_links.links_id
```

ficando assim:

```sql
links.id = pessoas_has_links.links_id
```

Desse modo, deverá ser retornado todos os registros que contenha o mesmo link. Ou então, mude `links.id` para `links.pessoa_id` ficando:

```sql
links.pessoa_id = pessoas_has_links.pessoas_id
```

Para que retorne todos os dados referente ao usuário especificado.

Verifique também se o join usado não pode estar interferindo nos resultados.

Comment: Bom dia, certo. na tabela "pessoas_has_links" na coluna "pessoa_id" o id se repete isso mostra que aquele usuario em especifico possui mais de um link, é isso que gostaria de checar pega o usuario(5) e visualizar quantos links ele possui. tentei da maneira que você mostrou acima mais trouxe todos os links de todos os usuarios.

Comment: @willianpereira você testou os dois? Verifique tbm se não seria outro tipo de join, talvez, o right

Comment: apenas o primeiro, mas fiquei na duvida, não seria necessário  especifica o id(5) para fazer essa ação? pra ele trazer somente esse usuario.

Comment: Tente o segundo tbm. Aí em pessoas_has_links.pessoas_id coloque o id do usuário.

Comment: na tabela "links" tenho a coluna "id" posso alterar ela pra "pessoa_id" sem problemas? e ao fazer isso a tabelas "pessoas_has_link" ja entende a conexão? ou terei que fazer manualmente ? sou novo em php haha

Comment: @willianpereira não indicaria, pois, a coluna id dessa tabela é o identificador dos registros dessa tabela e a tabela pessoas_has_links é quem faz a relação entre os registros da tabela link com a tabela pessoas. Indicaria estudar um pouco sobre relacionamentos SQL.

Comment: certo, muito obrigada